# how to get specific formula using RadioButton() in python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
r_value= StringVar()
r_value.set("R <= 10k")

def less10k():
    enrvalue0 = Vp/0.001 #enr formula for 1 mA
    return enrvalue0

Radiobutton(in_frame, text="Resistance Less than or Equal to 10k",variable=r_value, value="R <= 10k",font=24,command=less10k).grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="W")

def great10k():
    enrvalue1 = Vp/0.0001 #enr formula for 0.1 mA
    return enrvalue1

Radiobutton(in_frame, text="Resistance Greater than 10k", variable=r_value, value="R > 10k",font=24,command=great10k).grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="W")

pot=r_value.get()
if pot=="R <= 10k":
    enrvalue=less10k()
    print(0)
else:
    enrvalue=great10k()
    print(1)

if enrvalue<100:
    result =Label(out_frame, text="PASS", fg="white", bg="green", font=108,width=10,height=5).grid(row=0,column=4,rowspan=4)
else:
    result =Label(out_frame, text="FAIL", fg="white", bg="red", font=108,width=10,height=5).grid(row=0,column=4, rowspan=4)
```

I want that if I select 'R <= 10' it should select formula for 'enrvalue=Vp/0.001' and if I change to 'R > 10k' it should select 'enrvalue=Vp/0.0001'.
and also i want 'enrvalue' further to compare it by ideal value(100).
i want to know how can i change the value of 'pot' it always stick to my preset value of 'R <= 10k'.

Comment: You should put those checking code segments in a function which is triggered by, for example, a button. Suggest to go through some beginner tutorials on event-driven programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a default when you declare the r_value. The specific formula is run after the command triggers the function.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

Vp = 0.09
r_value = tk.StringVar(None, "R <= 10k")

root.result = tk.Label(root, fg='white', width=10, height=5)
root.result.grid(row=2)


def compare_10k():
    if r_value.get() == "R <= 10k":
        print(0)
        enrvalue = Vp / 0.001  # enr formula for 1 mA
    else:
        print(1)
        enrvalue = Vp / 0.0001  # enr formula for 0.1 mA

    if enrvalue < 100:
        root.result.configure(bg="green", text="PASS")
    else:
        root.result.configure(bg="red", text="FAIL")


tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Resistance Less than or Equal to 10k",
               variable=r_value,
               value="R <= 10k",
               font=24,
               command=compare_10k).grid(row=0, sticky="W")


tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Resistance Greater than 10k",
               variable=r_value,
               value="R > 10k",
               font=24,
               command=compare_10k).grid(row=1, sticky="W")

compare_10k()

root.mainloop()
```